# Is there a way to self generate similar key names and values in a dictionary with a loop?

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I want to create a dictionary by using a loop or similar technique. Something like the below variable assignment is possible.

```
my_dict = {v:int(v*random()) for v in range(10)}
```

Though the question I am stuck at- How can I generate similar names for the item keys? Giving an example below:

```
{'Item-1': 1, 'Item-2':3, 'Item-3':3 ....}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The key can be an arbitrary expression, just like the value. You don't have to use just `v` for the key in the dict comprehension,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import random

my_dict = {f'item-{v+1}': int(v*random()) for v in range(10)}
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

`{'item-1': 0, 'item-2': 0, 'item-3': 1, 'item-4': 1, 'item-5': 0, 'item-6': 3, 'item-7': 2, 'item-8': 4, 'item-9': 6, 'item-10': 2}`

This uses an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to create the key, the corresponding value is randomly generated like in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create keys and values and add to `my_dict` in a loop

```
my_dict = {}

for v in range(10): my_dict[f'Item-{v}'] = v

print(my_dict)

{'Item-0': 0, 'Item-1': 1, 'Item-2': 2, 'Item-3': 3, 'Item-4': 4, 'Item-5': 5, 'Item-6': 6, 'Item-7': 7, 'Item-8': 8, 'Item-9': 9}
```

Comment: Why should I assign 'v = np.arrange(0,10,1)' for? Can't I just assign 'my_dict[key] = v'? And the above solution is lengthy to me, that is why I asked for a quicker way. Still thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension in dictionaries too.

```
from random import randint

dic = {f"item-{i}": randint(0, 10) for i in range(1, 11)}


print(dic)
```

Comment: This isn't a list comprehension. This is just a dict comprehension. What you are doing is using an f-string as the key, rather than just the variable `i`.

Comment: that's what he's asking isn't it ?